# Java HashMap that can be accessed by hash

Tags: java, hashmap, overhead

I want to have a map in Java so I thought `HashMap`. But now, I want to overcome the overhead introduced by hashing. Basically there are objects that hold a key for the map for a very short time - but many of them, and polling/replacing a value often. So I thought the overhead from hashing the key every time `get()` or `set()` is being called could be significant and also overcome. So I thought of, with the key, saving the hash of the key - and reducing overhead.

Is it possible in Java to `get()` and `set()` a value with the key and a precomputed hash for the key - and of course getting that key from the map for consistency to avoid the overhead of the map having to hash the key?

Comment: "I want to have a map in Java that has a O(log n) access speed, so I thought HashMap" - that's strange of you to think that. HashMap is usual-case O(1), worst-case O(N). Order-based maps like TreeMap would be O(log n).

Comment: If you are asking if you can key a map on a hash itself rather than an object that generates a hash; then yes, that is basically what you get if you use `Integer` as the key type. Other than that, I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @khelwood If I use Integer, it will still hash the Integer, right? that sounds not like much overhead, definitly reduce, but not quite there. I'll consider it.

Comment: The hash of an `Integer` is just its value. That is as little overhead as you can get. Perhaps you are optimising in the wrong place.

Comment: @user2357112 Fixed in the question, it's basically about HashMaps cause HashMaps were timed to be the best

Comment: You can override your hash() method and do whatever pleases you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object can cache its hash code, so that when it's used repeatedly as a key, hashing overhead can be eliminated. For example, `java.lang.String` does this. The `Integer` class effectively does the same. Your custom key class can follow this pattern.

Comment: Java `String` and `Integer` support a unique pattern that the objects are shared. String literals and integers obtained via `Integer.valueOf(123)` follow that pattern. Caching the hash keys has obvious advantage following that pattern. Otherwise, you want to make sure the hash key is not repeatedly computed to justify caching.

Comment: I think the missing word throughout is immutability. If the obj is immutable **and** hashing is likely, it makes perfect sense to cache the hashCode eagerly. For any other scenario, there's a balance between lazy-caching and no-caching (also much simpler) that only a proper benchmark can decide.

Comment: It has nothing to do with shared instances. Most `String` instances are not interned, and only 256 `Integer` instances are guaranteed to be cached. Likewise, effective immutability is an important criterion for any hash key; but caching the hash code doesn't lend it any extra importance.